# Restrict user to delete Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-manifest

i want to make such an application that user is not allowed to uninstall it. As our company is going to launch our own android phone and  my application is going to preinstall in it..so that user wont be able to delete or uninstall it.
can anyone tell me how to achieve such a functionlity...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your company is going to launch its own android phone, put your application in the android source, like the other native applications (Settings, Gallery, etc). Also, modify the source, so that in `Settings --> Manage Applications` there is no entry for your application. If you install your application on a device by a installation manager or anything else then a user can uninstall your application. (You can't prevent this).